# NSInvocationOperation and main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, thread-safety, nsoperationqueue

Imagine that I have a view with some UIKit object as its subview (for example, `UIActivityIndicatorView` - this doesn't matter). This view also has a selector, called `doSomething`, which somehow manages UIKit object (in our example it can start or stop indicator view).

I create `NSInvocationOperation` (from view's code parts) with `initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doSomething) object:nil`. Then add it to `NSOperationQueue`. And all works fine.

How?! It should be a new thread and non-thread-safe UIKit object! Why no error found (and no crash happened)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `NSInvocationOperation` class is a concrete subclass of `NSOperation` that [implements a non-concurrent operation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In a non-concurrent operation, [the operation’s task is performed synchronously](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW15)—that is, the operation object does not create a separate thread on which to run the task. Thus, when the `start` method of a non-concurrent operation is called, the operation executes immediately in the current thread. By the time the `start` method of such an object returns control to the caller, the task itself is complete.

However, using `NSOperationQueue` changes this behavior. NSOperationQueue always executes operations concurrently; a non-concurrent operation requires a separate thread in order to execute concurrently, and `NSOperationQueue` provides this thread.

This means that if you'd execute your `NSInvocationOperation` directly, you'd be able to access your UIKit object thread-safe(the operation would run o the same thread). In your case, if using a `NSOperationQueue`, you should schedule the work that uses the UIKit object on the main thread, using NSObject's [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) from your invocation selector.